# SQL Multiple Inner Joins Between two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I know this is a fairly simple problem but its been years since I've looked at SQL.I have two tables that contain information..

The table Business Partners

```
Partner
1
2
3
```

and the table Business Relationships

```
RelationshipNum Partner1 Partner2 Relationshiptype
000001          1        2        OCDL
```

My query should take the values for Partner1 and Partner2 and search the field Partners in Business Partners. If both values on the same entry in Business Relationships are present the entire line in Business Relationships should be returned. If only one or none are present we can ignore it.

This is what I have so far but its returning no values, I've tested the dataset in excel(too large to be a viable option) and there are definitely matches.

```
SELECT  [Business Relationships].*
FROM [Business Relationships] 
INNER JOIN [Business Partners] ON ([Business Partners].Partner = [Business Relationships].Partner1) 
                               AND ([Business Partners].Partner = [Business Relationships].Partner2);
```

Comment: Assuming you're attempting to identify records where the Business Partner Id in the Relationships table is not defined in the BusinessPartners table, you might want to consider creating a foreign key relationship between the tables, thus enforcing this.

Answer (score 4):

Try with two `INNER JOIN` as below

```
SELECT  BR.*
FROM ([Business Relationships] BR
INNER JOIN [Business Partners] BP1 ON BP1.[Partner] = BR.[Partner1])
INNER JOIN [Business Partners] BP2 ON BP2.[Partner] = BR.[Partner2]
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response but I'm getting a "Syntax Error (missing operator) in query expression 'BP1.Partner = BR.Partner1 INNER JOIN [Business Partners] BP2 ON BP2.Partner = BR.Partner2" when I try to run the query.

Comment: @Quinn I added parenthesis try it now please.

Answer (score 2):

Use double `EXISTS` to find rows to return:

```
SELECT  BR.*
FROM [Business Relationships] BR
WHERE EXISTS (select 1 from [Business Partners] where Partner = BR.Partner1)
  AND EXISTS (select 1 from [Business Partners] where Partner = BR.Partner2)
```

Will never return any duplicates! (Which JOIN solutions may do, depending on data.)